# "Has ambiguous scrollable content width" error - fixing constraints not possible?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xcode5, constraints, autolayout

I am new to autolayout and iOS dev. In order to understand constraints, I am trying to rebuild an example out of a tutorial found here: http://bharathnagarajrao.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/demystifying-autolayouts-and-uiscrollview-part-1/

Despite redoing the example from scratch three times I always get the error "Has ambiguous scrollable content width". Has somebody an idea on how to fix that? I am attaching the two screenshots.

[image: constraints]

[image: errors]

Thank you in advance for any hint.